# Can't execute Python tasks: command 'python.*' not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

When I try to execute python commands, the commands look funny. They all start and end with a `%`. When I select one, I receive this error:

> command 'python.configureTests' not found

I tried re-installing the extension as well but no luck. See the below screenshot of when I try to execute a python command:

[image]